# Parse Job Scheduling

Tags: parse-platform, background, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a problem with the parse job scheduler. I have made a job that accepts some parameters and I want to run different instances of this job. Is there a way to do this? When I click on the Schedule a Job button it doesn't recognize a job that second time. It only lets me create the first job. And also in the new parse dashboard the schedule a job button is not even there.

Answer (score 0):

As a free users you can only schedule one single job. If you want to schedule more than one job you must pay for it. Take a look [here](https://www.parse.com/pricing) for more information.